# Angular JS-- Get value from textbox and use it for body background

Tags: angularjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="D:\Mano\Angular\Ex1\styles.css">

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-style="bColor">
    <mano-directive>
    </mano-directive>

    <form name="myForm">
        Email:
        <input type="email" name="remail" ng-model="mail">
        <span ng-show="myForm.remail.$error.email">Enter valid email</span>
        <br>
        <br> Valid: {{myForm.remail.$valid}}
        <br> Dirty: {{myForm.remail.$dirty}}
        <br> Touched: {{myForm.remail.$touched}}
        <br> {{mail}}
        <input type="button" ng-click="bColor={'background-color':'{{mail}}'}" value="Change Background"><!--mail variable not giving result--`enter code here`>

    </form>


    <script src="D:\Mano\Angular\Ex1\myApp.js"></script>
    <script src="D:\Mano\Angular\Ex1\myCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="D:\Mano\Angular\Ex1\myDir.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Angular JS-- Get value from textbox and use it for body background.
textbox values are supposed to be synchronized in mail variable, so, while button is clicked the value should be used as body background color
Kindly help

Comment: You should add a ng-pattern for HEX color :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove curly braces from `{{mail}}`

```
ng-click="bColor={'background-color': mail}"
```

Comment: On extending this program, I want a separate function and inside it I want change the color

Answer (score 0):

As @aseferov said remove curly braces. 
If you want to make sure that is a color into the textbox, just add a ng-pattern directive on your input to perform a validation.
The value will be updated only if the given value is trusted through ng-pattern.

Regex :  `ng-pattern="/^#?([a-fA-F0-9]{6}|[a-fA-F0-9]{3})$/"`

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="D:\Mano\Angular\Ex1\styles.css">

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-style="bColor">
    <mano-directive>
    </mano-directive>

    <form name="myForm">
        Email:
        <input type="text" name="remail" ng-model="dmail">
        <span ng-show="myForm.remail.$error.email">Enter valid email</span>
        <br>
        <br> Valid: {{myForm.remail.$valid}}
        <br> Dirty: {{myForm.remail.$dirty}}
        <br> Touched: {{myForm.remail.$touched}}
        <br>
        <p>{{dmail}}</p>
        <input type="button" ng-click="bColor={'background-color':dmail}" value="Change Background">

    </form>


    <script src="D:\Mano\Angular\Ex1\myApp.js"></script>
    <script src="D:\Mano\Angular\Ex1\myCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="D:\Mano\Angular\Ex1\myDir.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```